# Errors after changed OpenGL code from ES 1.0 to ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

I changed code from ES 1.0 to ES 2.0 in cocos2d-x

**Code in ES 1.0 version**

```
const float DARK=30.0f;
int n = m_sGridSize.x * m_sGridSize.y;
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);   
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_pVertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_pTexCoordinates);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, m_pIndices);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glColor4ub(255-(m_AnimationProgress*DARK), 255-(m_AnimationProgress*DARK), 255-(m_AnimationProgress*DARK), 255);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, m_pIndices);
glColor4f(255, 255, 255, 255);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

**Code in ES 2.0 version**

```
const float DARK=30.0f;
m_pShaderProgram->use();
m_pShaderProgram->setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix();
int n = m_sGridSize.x * m_sGridSize.y;
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_Color);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, m_pVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, m_pTexCoordinates);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, m_pIndices);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords);
ccDrawColor4B(255-(m_AnimationProgress*DARK), 255-(m_AnimationProgress*DARK), 255-(m_AnimationProgress*DARK), 255);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, m_pIndices);
ccDrawColor4B(255, 255, 255, 255);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttrib_Color);
```

**Results in the following output (XCode)**

```
Cocos2d: OpenGL error 0x0500 in /cocos2dx/sprite_nodes/CCSprite.cpp draw 616
```

**what did I do wrong?** I think all is well, a few times tested.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenGL ES 1.1, texture mapping for fragments (there's no vertex texture mapping in ES 1.1) is turned on and off, using `glEnable`, and `glDisable`, respectively.

In OpenGL ES 2.0, fragment texture mapping is only done if it's coded into the fragment shader, so there's no need to enable or disable it.  I suspect the GL_INVALID_ENUM is from the leftover `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` and `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`.  I'm guessing you're seeing that error more than once.

Answer (score 1):

0x0500 is an "illegal enum" error. [Check the error codes here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes).

This most likely refers to the enums like GL_CULL_FACE or GL_TRIANGLES. Refer to the DL ES reference which ones might not be available in 2.0, or which of those can't be used under certain circumstances.